# plugin-list-category-post custom fields

Tags: custom-field, plugin-list-category-post

I'm using list category posts and would like to display several custom fields, but not all together.

I have used a template to display the list in a table, and have custom fields for country, county and town that I would like to display in individual cells.
These are the only custom fields I will be using, so I can hard code the names in the template is necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_post_meta(). This is the codex article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

It sounds like each of the custom field values you want to display would only contain one result (one country, one town etc). In that case you'd use something like this in your template, wherever you want to display the value:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'country', true) ) : ?>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'country', true) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps, best of luck!

Comment: Great! If this works for you, you can mark the answer as accepted so other people don't spend time on it. :)